# On query delete redirect to page?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I'm using this script to add a user to favourites on the first click of a button, and on the second click it will remove the user from favourites.

When adding a user to favorites/when the query runs 'insert into' it will redirect back to the previous page after it has completed but if you then click the second time to un add users from favorites it won't redirect, your just on a blank page with a number 1 displayed.

Can anyone suggest how i can get it to redirect back to the previous page same as when adding a user to favourites?

Also how could i get it to redirect back to the previous page and display an echoed out message saying added to favorites or deleted from favourites?

I am new to php and mysql and still learning so i appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
<?php

    require_once('includes/session.php');
    require_once('includes/functions.php');
    require('includes/_config/connection.php');

    session_start();

        confirm_logged_in();

        if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
        $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


    }


    if (!isset($_GET['to']))
        exit('No user specified.');

    $user_id = $_GET['to'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_favorites (user_id, favorite_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")") 
    or die(mysql_query("DELETE FROM ptb_favorites WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND favorite_id = ".$user_to_id."")); header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

    #Method to go to previous page

    function goback()

    {

        header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

        exit;

    }

    goback();


    ?>
```

Comment: where's the code that removes the user from favorites ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using `die()` for this. You should create a function that will check if the users favorite already exists and create or delete and redirect accordingly.

Also, move to mysqli_ or PDO! :)

Comment: ok thanks i will do, do you also have any ideas on how i can echo a message out on the previous page after it redirects?

Comment: I'm not following - echo a message on the the page you just redirected *from*?

Comment: no so say i'm on the user's profile (profile.php) i then click the add them to favourites button, which links me to favourite.php to carry out the fuction, and then redirects me back to profile.php, i then want to echo a message on the profile.php page saying added user to favourites.

Comment: you can have your favourite.php pass that back to profile.php to read. You can do it by putting that in the query string and retrieving it with GET

Comment: ok i've never done that before, would i please be able to ask you for an example code?

Comment: Real simple... In favourite.php: `header("Location: /profile.php?fav=1");` I put 'fav', but you can really use anything. Then on profile.php: `if ($_GET['fav'] == 1) { echo 'Favourite has been added!'; }`

Comment: ok but i've noticed you put header("Location: /profile.php?fav=1"); does that mean i can't use it with this: header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");    ?

Comment: Sure you can: `header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}?fav=1");`

Comment: ok, well i've used that code you gave me and still no message being echoed out, could you check the other code for me that i'm using to see if there would be any reason why the message wouldn't echo out:

Comment: <?
if (isset($_GET['fav']) && $_GET['fav'] == 1) {
   $message = "<div class=\"infobox-profile\"><strong>Added to Favourites.</strong>This user has been added to your favourites.</div>";
   echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close3\"></div></a>";
   
}
?>

Comment: no couldn't get it to work, for some reason no message is being echoed, so i was asking if you could see any obvious reason in my code thats echoing out the message to see what the problem is?

Comment: @JamesMatthews - Do you see your query string in the address bar of the browser after the redirect? If not, there is something wrong with how you are passing it. If you can see it, than you are reading it wrong or not echo'ing correctly.

Comment: yes i can see the redirect in the url. it's got to be a problem with the echo part but i don't know why, it should work.

Comment: @JamesMatthews - It looks like you are assigning it to the variable `$message`, but never echoing it...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
or die(mysql_query("DELETE FROM ptb_favorites WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND favorite_id = ".$user_to_id."")); header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

with

```
or mysql_query("DELETE FROM ptb_favorites WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND favorite_id = ".$user_to_id.""); header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

But it would be better to check recird existance and then either insert or delete.

Comment: thanks this works great, any ideas on how i can echo a message out on the previous page after it redirects?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using die(), you may want to write a function to check if a user is a favorite or not, then call a corresponding MySQL query.  For example, you could try using this code, adding some extra checks and security if necessary:

```
function userIsFavorite($user_id, $favorite_id) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ptb_favorites WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND favorite_id='$favorite_id'");
    return (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0);
}

if (userIsFavorite($_SESSION['user_id'], $user_to_id)) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM ptb_favorites WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND favorite_id='".$user_to_id."'");
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_favorites (user_id, favorite_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")");
}

header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

Comment: Oops, I changed a line from:
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ptb_favorites WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND favorite_id = ".$user_to_id"");
to:
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ptb_favorites WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND favorite_id='".$user_to_id"'");

Comment: I fixed another error - sorry I don't have a php installation running at the moment to test it on.